# Pre_ and Post_ Events

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I am creating an class library in C++/CLI to be used with C#, and as part of that library, i am offering up a customised version of `System.Windows.Forms.Form` and `System.Windows.Forms.Control` as `System.Windows.Forms.HAForm` and `System.Windows.Forms.HAControl`. I want to override `OnPaint` in a way that allows me to have `OnPaint_Pre`, `OnPaint_Post` AND `OnPaint` as i need to handle certain things every time before any painting is done, and handle some things AFTER painted has completed.

While this alone is simple enough, with this being a class in a library that is to be inherited from, i do not want to simply create an `OnPaint` in my class as this will be overwritten by the end developers `OnPaint`, and even if they do call `base.OnPaint`, the events will be fired out of order. i.e. OnPaint_Pre, my `OnPaint`, `OnPaint_Post`, sub classes `OnPaint`.

How would i create a class that inserts two events, one before the existing event, and one after?

Comment: That's easy, override OnPaint :)  And no, the problem with virtual methods is that an unwitting client programmer can always break you.  Unless you use the *sealed* keyword on your method so they can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't mind me using C# syntax instead of C++/CLI...

You can make the HAForm/HAControl OnPaint override sealed, and create a new virtual function that derived classes can override. You can even use an intermediate class to give the new virtual function the same name:

```
public class HAControlBase : Control
{
    protected virtual void OnPaintPre(PaintEventArgs e) { }
    protected virtual void OnPaintPost(PaintEventArgs e) { }

    internal virtual void OnPaintImpl(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
    protected sealed override OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        OnPaintPre(e);
        OnPaintImpl(e);
        OnPaintPost(e);
    }
}

public class HAControl : HAControlBase
{
    internal sealed override void OnPaintImpl(PaintEventArgs e) {
        OnPaint(e);
    }
    protected new virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaintImpl(e);
    }
}
```

Now, even if a derived class overrides `HAControl.OnPaint`, it will only be called after `HAControlBase.OnPaint` has already finished with `OnPaintPre`, there is no way to override `Control.OnPaint` (because that override is `sealed`) to call anything before `OnPaintPre`.